# How to jump an equation number

Tags: equations, numbering

I want to reference an equation from a book, and so I tag the equation (`\tag{10.6}`) for it to match the equation number from the book. That way I by purpose screw up my numbering so it goes (2.1), (2.2), (2.3), (10.6), (2.4), (2.5) and so on. But it gives me a problem when I reach section 10, because then the numbering will be like usual: (10.4), (10.5), (10.6), (10.7), and therefore the equation number will be doubled.

Is there a way for LaTeX to automatically skip that single number? I can of course just manually skip it by `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` but then that messes up as soon as I remove or add another equation, and it isn't very neat...

Comment: Perhaps label the imported equation something like `\tag{10.6*}`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `\newtagform` from `mathtools` and `\tag`. and adding some letter in front of the equation number to differentiate both equations. This way you'll be able to reference both.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{book}{(B\,}{)}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{10}
\usetagform{book}
\begin{equation}
\label{bkeq}\tag {10.1}
  a =b + d
\end{equation}
\usetagform{default}
From {\usetagform{book}\eqref{bkeq}} we deduce:
\begin{equation}
\label{myeq}
c = d × e
\end{equation}
But \eqref{myeq} does not imply {\usetagform{book}\eqref{bkeq}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this

```
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
\thechapter.\ifnum\value{equation}<6 \arabic{equation}\else\the\numexpr\value{equation}+1\relax\fi}
```

and restore old definition in next chapter.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
\thechapter.\ifnum\value{equation}<6 \arabic{equation}\else\the\numexpr\value{equation}+1\relax\fi}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{g}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{f}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{ff}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{gg}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\ref{ff}**\ref{f}**\ref{gg}**\ref{g}

\chapter{foo}
\let\theequation\oldtheequation
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
bb
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```